# How can i send an email to me with information the user typed?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

Good afternoon, I am trying to create a part of an application that makes the user answer some questions within the app itself and when clicking on the button to send, create an automatic email body with the information that was filled in within the app. For example: Name: Bernardo; thus, in the body of the e-mail, "Name: Bernardo" will appear without the user having to write again. For now, I can only make the text of the email capture "Name: null" and I don't know what I can do so that the information filled in the application is captured correctly. The problem seems to be either within the `public void pegarTexto` or in `emailIntent.putExtra (android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT`, I'm certainly doing something wrong, but I can't identify it. If anyone can help I will be grateful. If the question is not clear I ask you to leave tips on how to improve it in the comments please, because I'm a beginner! Here is the code:

```
public class DiagnosticoFragment extends Fragment {
    EditText editTextNome, editTextTelefone, editTextEmail, editTextEndereco, editTextBairro, editTextCidade, editTextEstado, editTextHorario, editTextComoConheceu, editTextConteMais;
    String nome, telefone, email, endereco, bairro, cidade, estado, horario, comoconheceu, contemais;



public DiagnosticoFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
public void pegarTexto(View view){
    editTextNome = view.findViewById(R.id.editTextNome);
    editTextTelefone = view.findViewById(R.id.editTextTelefone);
    editTextEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextEndereco = view.findViewById(R.id.editTextEndereco);
    editTextBairro = view.findViewById(R.id.editTextBairro);
    editTextCidade = view.findViewById(R.id.editTextCidade);
    editTextEstado = view.findViewById(R.id.editTextEstado);
    editTextHorario = view.findViewById(R.id.editTextHorario);
    editTextComoConheceu = view.findViewById(R.id.editTextComoConheceu);
    editTextConteMais = view.findViewById(R.id.editTextConteMais);

    nome = editTextNome.getText().toString();
    telefone = editTextTelefone.getText().toString();
    email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
    endereco = editTextEndereco.getText().toString();
    bairro = editTextBairro.getText().toString();
    cidade = editTextCidade.getText().toString();
    estado = editTextEstado.getText().toString();
    horario = editTextHorario.getText().toString();
    comoconheceu = editTextComoConheceu.getText().toString();
    contemais = editTextConteMais.getText().toString();

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_diagnostico, container, false);
    Button btnSendEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.btnSendEmail);

    btnSendEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // cria um intent
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            // define o email especifico pre definido
            String[] recipients = new String[]{
                    "contato@metaconsultoria.com"
            };
            // insere o email no extra
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
            // define um assunto
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Possível projeto.");
            // define o conteúdo do email
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Nome: " + nome + "Telefone: " + telefone + "E-mail: " + email + "Endereço: " + endereco + "Bairro: " + bairro
                    + "Cidade: " + cidade + "Estado: " + estado + "Horário: " + horario + "Como conheceu a Meta: " + comoconheceu + "Conte mais: " + contemais );
            // definido o tipo
            emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
            // inicia o intent
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Enviar email..."));
        }
    });

    return view;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using F10 to step into each line one-by-one to determine where the value is null. You will need to set a break point prior to doing this, however.

Answer (score -1):

Heyy,

refer to this I use it to for myself to send emails

```
private void sendMessage(String etContent, String etHeader)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("message/rfc822");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL , new String[]{"email@gmail.com"});
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT , etHeader);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT , etContent);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.setPackage("com.google.android.gm");
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent , "Email via"));
            Log.i("Finished sending email...", "");
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

Compare and see whats wrong!!